# How can I make two tables fill each others NAs?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I'm stuck with a slight problem I have with two data frames. Basically, both contain values and NAs and have the exact same format (columns, names, etc) and each table is 292 rows long.

The NAs in one correspond to values in the other one and vice versa e.g. the first three lines from the top table are NAs in the bottom table while the 4th and 5th row in the bottom table are NA in the top table.

I'm looking for a way to merge these two tables in order to minimize the number of NAs i.e. take row 1, 2 and 3 from the top table and the 4th row from the bottom table and so on. (I know that row 2 is NA in both; the end results will still have NAs, just a lot less). Can anybody help me out?

P.S. I've already tried all the joining and/or merging functions I know from base R and from the dplyr package.

Thanks in Advance.

```
   > head(extracted1)
     sex feet inches in_inches  in_cm
1   Male    6      0        72 182.88
2   Male   NA     NA        NA     NA
3 Female    5      3        63 160.02
4 Female   NA     NA        NA     NA
5   Male   NA     NA        NA     NA
6   Male    6      0        72 182.88

head(extracted2)
     sex feet   inches in_inches in_cm
1   Male   NA       NA        NA    NA
2   Male   NA       NA        NA    NA
3 Female   NA       NA        NA    NA
4 Female    5 4.960630  64.96063   165
5   Male   16 9.181102 201.18110   511
6   Male   NA       NA        NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Base-r`. This code takes the rows with no NAs from both dataframes with `complete.cases` and binds them together with `rbind`

```
rbind(extracted1[complete.cases(extracted1),],extracted2[complete.cases(extracted2),])


     sex feet   inches in_inches  in_cm
1   Male    6 0.000000  72.00000 182.88
3 Female    5 3.000000  63.00000 160.02
6   Male    6 0.000000  72.00000 182.88
4 Female    5 4.960630  64.96063 165.00
5   Male   16 9.181102 201.18110 511.00
```

**edit:**

if you want to keep the same structure of `extracted1` you can do the following also in `Base-R`

```
toreplace <- extracted2[complete.cases(extracted2),]
extracted1[as.numeric(row.names(toreplace)),] <- toreplace

     sex feet   inches in_inches  in_cm
1   Male    6 0.000000  72.00000 182.88
2   Male   NA       NA        NA     NA
3 Female    5 3.000000  63.00000 160.02
4 Female    5 4.960630  64.96063 165.00
5   Male   16 9.181102 201.18110 511.00
6   Male    6 0.000000  72.00000 182.88
```

Comment: Simple and elegant! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @N.A. out of curiosity, which version was better for your needs? the one that omits the NAs or the one that keeps the structure intact?

Comment: the second one, since I don't want to lose the points that are NAs. Now I have to figure out how to replace these new 292 values in the original table (1k+).